# Symfony locks: Blocking + remote

Tags: php, symfony, locking

I would like to use a [symfony lock](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html) that is both **remote** and **blocking**.

From the documentation, none of the available store allow to do that:

[image: Available locks stores]

- Do you know why ?
- Is there another way to do this ?